# how to make spatial sandbox application's solr core accessible with multiple tomcat web apps

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr, spatial

I have Apache Tomcat 7.0.25, JRE 1.7.0_02 and Solr 4.0 installed. I have compiled [spatial solr sandbox application](https://github.com/ryantxu/spatial-solr-sandbox/tree/master/spatial-demo).

Application create Solr 5.0-SNAPSHOT core. As I need both SOLRs running, I setup multiple web applications in Tomcat by adding xml in `apache-tomcat-7.0.25/conf/Catalina/localhost`. Here I set path to spatial solr sandbox war file. Old SOLR is running on localhost */solr* and sandbox application on */spatial*. The web application is running perfectly but it's solr core is not accessible on */spatial/solr*. I realized i have to set it's path in `apache-tomcat-7.0.25/webapps/spatial/WEB-INF/web.xml`, I tried this and million other combinations but without success:

```
  <filter-name>SolrRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>path-prefix</param-name>
      <param-value>/spatial/solr</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SolrRequestFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/spatial/solr/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

So my question is how can I make spatial sandbox application's solr core accessible on */spatial/solr*?

Answer (score 0):

Spatial-Solr-Sandbox is a demonstration and tool. It makes hard-coded assumptions that Solr is available at "/solr/". I suggest not trying to deploy it to anything; just run it via "mvn jetty:run".